# Save contacts to CardDAV adress book with Python

Tags: python, owncloud, carddav

I want to save some contacts into a CardDAV address book running on a OwnCloud server.
Is there an easy way to do this with python?

I have tried python-pycarddav but it is very hard to start because I could not find a manual or a example for us this with Python.
Also they wrote: "pycarddav is DEPRECATED - use vdirsyncer & khard"

Comment: The CardDAV client `pyCardDAV` has as one of its features that it's tested against owncloud, so that might be what you are looking for? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyCardDAV/

Comment: Thank you, that was the first thing I have tried. But it is very hard so start  because I could not find a manual or a example for us this with Python.

Comment: If you really just want to save (create) them, render them as a vCard and PUT them into the server? Just using httplib.